# query DSL : test cases that use query DSL works fine, but editor pane of IntelliJ reports that generated meta models cannot be resolved

Tags: java, intellij-idea, querydsl

I am trying to integrate query DSL with Spring, Gradle, and IntelliJ 15. I've configured my IntelliJ project after checking out [this link](http://bsideup.blogspot.kr/2015/04/querydsl-with-gradle-and-idea.html). It leads executing a test case method that use query DSL to a green light, but editor pane still reports that meta models (Q classes) cannot be resolved. except things that the link provides, Is there something that I have to configure, in order to fix this IDE error?

Here's what I have tried:

- enabled annotation processor on Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Annotation Processors
- in "Store generated sources relative to:" select Module content root.
- make sure that the generated folder is registered on Project Structure.
- imported two dependencies to build.gradle: querydsl-jpa and querydsl-apt.
- added the following script to build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
idea {
        module {
            sourceDirs += file('generated/')
        }
    }
```

if you want to check out a minimum implementation of this problem, `git-clone` [this](https://github.com/bsideup/querydsl-gradle-idea/). any comments would be awesome. 'It works for my desktop' would be OK!! I really need your help.

Comment: I think you are missing dependency: querydsl-core

Comment: just added `compile "com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-core:3.6.3"`. still not working. can you apply your solution to the minimum implementation yourself?